# Is there a simple expression for $\sum_{k =1}^{(p-3)/2} \frac{1\cdot 3\cdots (2k-1)}{2\cdot 4 \cdots 2k\cdot(2k+1)} \bmod p$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series

Let $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ be a prime and $E_n$ denote the $n$-th Euler number.  While investigating $E_{p-1} \pmod{p^2}$ I have encountered this summation (modulo $p$)
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k =1}^{\frac{p-3}{2}} \frac{a_k}{2k+1} \pmod p.
\end{align*}
where $a_k = \frac{1\cdot 3\cdots (2k-1)}{2\cdot 4 \cdots 2k}$.

Another way to express this sum (this is how I first saw it) is
\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 1}^{\frac{p-3}{2}} {2k \choose k} \frac{1}{4^k(2k + 1)}.
\end{align}

Like the questions says, I am wondering if a simple expression is known for this sum, or if sums like it have been studied before.  Any references or insights would be appreciated!

**Some observations:** Using Wilson's theorem, we have
\begin{align}
\frac{1\cdot 3\cdots (p-2)}{2\cdot 4 \cdots (p-1)} \equiv \frac{-1}{(2\cdot 4 \cdots (p-1))^2} \equiv \frac{-1}{2^{p-1}\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)^2!} \equiv 1 \pmod p
\end{align}
($p \equiv 1 \pmod 4 \implies \left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)^2!\equiv -1 \pmod p$).  Hence
\begin{align}
\frac{1\cdot 3\cdots (2k-1)}{2\cdot 4 \cdots 2k} \equiv \frac{1\cdot 3\cdots (p-2(k+1))}{2\cdot 4 \cdots (p-(2(k+1)-1))} \pmod p
\end{align}
then $a_k \equiv a_{\frac{p-1}{2}-k} \pmod p$
and the sum collapses a bit,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k =1}^{\frac{p-3}{2}} \frac{a_k}{2k+1} \equiv \sum_{k =1}^{\frac{p-3}{4}} \frac{a_k}{2k+1} - \sum_{k =1}^{\frac{p-3}{4}} \frac{a_{\frac{p-1}{2}-k}}{2k} \equiv -\sum_{k =1}^{\frac{p-3}{4}} \left(\frac{a_k}{(2k)(2k+1)} \right) \pmod p
\end{align*}
but this doesn't seem to help.  The symmetry of $a_k$ described above gives $\sum_{k =1}^{\frac{p-3}{2}}(-1)^k a_k \equiv 0 \pmod p$, which may be of interest to others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is known that $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\binom{2k}k}{(2k+1)4^k}=\frac{\pi}2.$$ Motivated by this, I proved in my paper [*On congruences related to central binomial coefficients*](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jnt.2011.04.004) [J. Number Theory 131(2011), 2219-2238] the following result (as part (i) of Theorem 1.1 in the paper):

Let $p$ be any odd prime. Then
$$\sum_{k=0}^{(p-3)/2}\frac{\binom{2k}k}{(2k+1)4^k}\equiv(-1)^{(p+1)/2}\frac{2^{p-1}-1}p\pmod{p^2}$$
and
$$\sum_{k=(p+1)/2}^{p-1}\frac{\binom{2k}k}{(2k+1)4^k}\equiv pE_{p-3}\pmod{p^2},$$
where $E_0,E_1,E_2,\ldots$ are the Euler numbers.

Comment: Of course, $$\sum_{k=1}^{(p-3)/2}\frac{\binom{2k}k}{(2k+1)4^k}=\sum_{k=0}^{(p-3)/2}\frac{\binom{2k}k}{(2k+1)4^k}-1.$$

Comment: The result indicates that it is natural to let $k$ start from $0$ rather than from $1$. Please  note the infinite series for $\pi/2$.

Comment: Note that a prime such that $\tfrac{2^{p-1}-1}{p} \equiv 0 \bmod p$ is called a Wieferich prime https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wieferich_prime . Only two such are known, 1093 and 3511, and there are very few results about them.

Comment: Note that the two congruences stated above already have the modulus $p^2$.